# Copy last line of a local file onto a file on a remote server

Tags: command-line, copy, tail

I hope the title makes sense.

I am trying to copy the last line of a file onto a file with same name on a remote server.

For example:  copy last line of server1:/opt/users.txt  to server2:/opt/users.txt

server1: cat /opt/users.txt

1. john
2. Kathy
3. Sierra

server2: cat /opt/users.txt

1. john
2. Kathy

`copy last line of server1:/opt/users.txt  to server2:/opt/users.txt`

output

server2: cat /opt/users.txt

1. John
2. Kathy
3. Sierra

Comment: How do you access the server? Is the server file always equal to the local file, except for the last line? If yes, that would be simplified to "copy a file to a server.

Answer (score 4):

From `server1`, assuming that `user` has appropriate permissions to write to the file:

```
tail -n 1 /opt/users.txt | ssh user@server2 'cat - >> /opt/users.txt'
```

Comment: Thank you @steeldriver. I have been working on that this morning and could not make it work. This is exactly what i was looking for. Cheers!!